# How to access syntax elements

Tags: syntax-highlighting, regular-expression

I try to inline one syntax in another syntax (to be explicit: CSS in JS template strings). I'd like to build on top of the existing CSS definitions and not create new ones.

Question: Is it possible to access previously defined syntax matches/keywords for access in other syntax definitions?

---

Example:

Imagine the following definition:

```
syn keyword cssPseudoClassId contained link visited active
syn match   cssPseudoClassId contained "\<first-\(line\|letter\)\>"
```

How do I access cssPseudoClassId to include it in another syntax definition to not re-write it manually.

```
syn region customWhatever transparent fold
        \ start=":".cssPseudoClassId end="\ze\(,\|;\|...\)"
        \ skip="\\\(`\|\$\)" ...
        \ contains=css.*Prop,...
```

Any other tips are highly appreciated.

Comment: To resolve this particular issue I may get by, by adding `cssPseudoClassId` to the `contains`-section. But the general question would still be interesting to have answered.